# Java Swing: dynamic add jpanels not visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, flowlayout

I am trying to add dynamically new jpanels (dimension 250x500_ in a JScrollPane by pressing a JButton. The width of the JScrollPane is 1024, a little more than 4 JPanels.

For the 4 first JButton clicks, 4 JPanels are inserted normally. 
If I click the button and a 5th time then the JScrollPane grows(the vertical bar gets visible and creates some space, also the data under the jpanel are correct) but, unfortunately, the new JPanel is not visible.

If I click the JButton and a 6th time then the JScrollPane grows more and the 5th JPanel gets visible (and goes on...)

Any suggestions on why that happens?
(I use flow layout inside the JScrollPane)

EDIT: Apparently I already work with validating and repaint methods because as I wrote above, the jpanel gets visible 4 out of 5 times... The problem lies in the 5th click that the new JPanel does not fit in the existing JScroll and it doesn't appear (due to JScroll is getting larger). In the 6th click, the 5th JPanel appears and goes on...

Please dont be critical before understand.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Components has a size of (0, 0) when created. The layout manager needs to be invoked before a component has a size and location.

The basic code for dynamically adding components to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout managers
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

If this doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Seriously? You answered this type of question yesterday, in fact, I'm pretty sure you answer a question like this once a day :P